# Keep only date part when using pandas.to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, series

I use `pandas.to_datetime` to parse the dates in my data. Pandas by default represents the dates with `datetime64[ns]` even though the dates are all daily only.
I wonder whether there is an elegant/clever way to convert the dates to `datetime.date` or `datetime64[D]` so that, when I write the data to CSV, the dates are not appended with `00:00:00`. I know I can convert the type manually element-by-element:

```
[dt.to_datetime().date() for dt in df.dates]
```

But this is really slow since I have many rows and it sort of defeats the purpose of using `pandas.to_datetime`. Is there a way to convert the `dtype` of the entire column at once? Or alternatively, does `pandas.to_datetime` support a precision specification so that I can get rid of the time part while working with daily data?

Answer (score 609):

[Since version `0.15.0`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.15.0.html) this can now be easily done using [`.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#dt-accessor) to access just the date component:

```
df['just_date'] = df['dates'].dt.date
```

The above returns `datetime.date`, so `object` dtype. If you want to keep the dtype as `datetime64` then you can just [`normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html#pandas.Series.dt.normalize):

```
df['normalised_date'] = df['dates'].dt.normalize()
```

This sets the time component to midnight, i.e. `00:00:00`, but the display shows just the date value.

- [`pandas.Series.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html)

Comment: @edChum any way to format date in MM-DD-YYYY format?

Comment: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Answer (score 92):

**Simple Solution:**

```
df['date_only'] = df['date_time_column'].dt.date
```

Comment: Just a warning, this changes the type to object. So you'd need to astype('datetime64') to keep consistency.

Answer (score 41):

While I upvoted [EdChum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34277514/4518341), which is the most direct answer to the question the OP posed, it does not really solve the performance problem (it still relies on python `datetime` objects, and hence any operation on them will be not vectorized - that is, it will be slow).

[A better performing alternative](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14669#issuecomment-261080259) is:

```
df['dates'].dt.floor('d')
```

Strictly speaking, it does not "keep only date part", since it just sets the time to `00:00:00`. But it does work as desired by the OP when, for instance:

- printing to screen
- saving to csv
- using the column to `groupby`

... and it is much more efficient, since the operation is vectorized.

**EDIT:** in fact, the answer the OP's would have preferred is probably "recent versions of `pandas` do *not* write the time to csv if it is `00:00:00` for all observations".

Comment: Unfortunately `to_json` still writes the full `00:00:00`.

Comment: @IanS do you mean when using ``date_format='iso'``?! By default, it just outputs seconds since epoch.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: This is faster than `dt.normalize()` on series longer than a few hundred elements.

Comment: On a df of >1 million rows, this was far faster than any of the other options I found, with the exception of `normalize` which was only slightly slower. In addition, keeping the date pandas-native means it can be saved to hdf stores (datetime.date columns cannot be as of pandas 1.1.4).

Comment: This method keeps the 'dates' column as a date format, so I think it is the best method to be able to filter the dataframe by date.

Answer (score 23):

#### Pandas v0.13+: Use [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) with `date_format` parameter

Avoid, where possible, converting your `datetime64[ns]` series to an `object` dtype series of `datetime.date` objects. The latter, often constructed using [`pd.Series.dt.date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html), is stored as an array of pointers and is inefficient relative to a pure NumPy-based series.

Since your concern is **format when writing to CSV**, just use the `date_format` parameter of `to_csv`. For example:

```
df.to_csv(filename, date_format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

See [Python's `strftime` directives](http://strftime.org/) for formatting conventions.

Answer (score 22):

This is a simple way to extract the date:

```
import pandas as pd

d='2015-01-08 22:44:09' 
date=pd.to_datetime(d).date()
print(date)
```

Comment: The OP is already using the .date() method in their question, so this solution doesn't answer their question, but I did find it useful to see a simple example of using the date() method just as a reference.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work whne used as a lambda function for the date parser i.e. date_parser=lambda col: pd.to_datetime(col, format="%y%m%d").date()

Answer (score 21):

Pandas `DatetimeIndex` and `Series` have a method called [`normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html#pandas.Series.dt.normalize) that does exactly what you want.

You can read more about it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26883852/512111).

It can be used as `ser.dt.normalize()`

Answer (score 18):

```
df['Column'] = df['Column'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

This will give you just the dates and NO TIME at your desired format. You can change format according to your need `'%m/%d/%Y'`. It will change the data type of the column to `'object'`.

---

If you want just the dates and DO NOT want time in `YYYY-MM-DD` format use :

```
df['Column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column']).dt.date
```

The datatype will be `'object'`.

---

For `'datetime64'` datatype, use:

```
df['Column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column']).dt.normalize()
```

Answer (score 15):

Just giving a more up to date answer in case someone sees this old post.

Adding "utc=False" when converting to datetime will remove the timezone component and keep only the date in a datetime64[ns] data type.

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], utc=False)
```

You will be able to save it in excel without getting the error "ValueError: Excel does not support datetimes with timezones. Please ensure that datetimes are timezone unaware before writing to Excel."

[image]

Comment: This for some reason fails after you apply any aggregate function with the column.

Comment: @Katekarin if you try and see df['Date'].values  its will still have the time component present in it.

Answer (score 6):

Converting to `datetime64[D]`:

```
df.dates.values.astype('M8[D]')
```

Though re-assigning that to a DataFrame col will revert it back to [ns].

If you wanted actual `datetime.date`:

```
dt = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.dates)
dates = np.array([datetime.date(*date_tuple) for date_tuple in zip(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day)])
```

Comment: If you are using astype('M8[D]') it transforms missing values into the origin date, 1970-1-1. Probably better to just use pandas.to_datetime() nowadays.

Comment: Note to anyone who routinely includes the datetime module as `dt`, this answer snipet will overwrite that module! @Dale-Jung, perhaps could change the line to something like dt_index

Comment: I'm also finding an issue whereby the next time I try and add a new row via the `df.loc[date]` method, the index reverts back to a timestamp, meaning subsequent comparisons no longer work

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to be able to change the type for a set of columns in a data frame and then remove the time keeping the day. [round(), floor(), ceil()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/whatsnew.html#datetimelike-rounding) all work

```
df[date_columns] = df[date_columns].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df[date_columns] = df[date_columns].apply(lambda t: t.dt.floor('d'))
```

Answer (score 4):

On tables of >1000000 rows I've found that these are both fast, with `floor` just slightly faster:

```
df['mydate'] = df.index.floor('d')
```

or

```
df['mydate'] = df.index.normalize()
```

If your index has timezones and you don't want those in the result, do:

```
df['mydate'] = df.index.tz_localize(None).floor('d')
```

`df.index.date` is many times slower; `to_datetime()` is even worse. Both have the further disadvantage that the results cannot be saved to an hdf store as it does not support type datetime.date.

Note that I've used the index as the date source here; if your source is another column, you would need to add `.dt`, e.g. `df.mycol.dt.floor('d')`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on UTC Timestamp (2020-08-19T09:12:57.945888)

```
for di, i in enumerate(df['YourColumnName']):
    df['YourColumnName'][di] = pd.Timestamp(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column is not already in datetime format:

```
df['DTformat'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'])
```

Once it's in datetime format you can convert the entire column to date only like this:

```
df['DateOnly'] = df['DTformat'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
```