# Reset time part of a pandas timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timestamp

How can I reset the time part of a pandas timestamp?

I want to reset time part in value of pandas.Timestamp.
I guess I can do it using the following procedure.

- step 1) Timestamp to datetime type
- step 2) datetime to seconds
- step 3) truncate time part in seconds
- step 4) bring back seconds to Timestamp

Even if my guess is correct, it takes too long to do.
Is there a straightforward way to achieve this goal?

> In [371]: ts = pd.Timestamp('2014/11/12 13:35')
>
> In [372]: ts
>
> Out[372]: Timestamp('2014-11-12 13:35:00')
>
> In [373]: ts.hour = 0 # <-- this is what I am trying to do.

Comment: If you are dealing with a ``DatetimeIndex``, you can use the `normalize` method. This is however not availabe on the individual Timestamp (a workaround is: `pd.DatetimeIndex([ts]).normalize()[0]`)

Comment: Do you want to reset the 'whole' time part (only keep date), or do you only want to reset the hours?

Answer (score 44):

I think you are looking for the `replace` method (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace)):

```
In [18]: ts
Out[18]: Timestamp('2014-11-12 13:35:00')

In [19]: ts.replace(hour=0)
Out[19]: Timestamp('2014-11-12 00:35:00')
```

This is a method inherited from `datetime.datetime`

If you want to reset the full time part, you specify all parts in `replace`:

```
In [20]: ts.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
Out[20]: Timestamp('2014-11-12 00:00:00')
```

There is also a `DatetimeIndex.normalize` method, but this isn't available on the individual Timestamps (I opened an issue for that: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8794):

```
In [21]: pd.DatetimeIndex([ts]).normalize()[0]
Out[21]: Timestamp('2014-11-12 00:00:00')
```

Comment: The most valuable thing here, pandas timestamp is inherited from datetime!!! If I had known that, I wouldn't have been so scared. :) Thank you!

Comment: The replace method does not seem to work on a column, does it? `AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Comment: Indeed, that is not available on a column/index. In that case you will need to use something like `df["col"].apply(lambda ts: ts.replace(..))` if you want to use `replace` (but note that the `normalize` is available on a column).

Answer (score 2):

Note that the `replace` method does not change the Timestamp, so if you want to keep the modified Timestamp you have to assign:

```
In [2]: ts = pd.Timestamp('2014/11/12 13:35')
In [3]: ts.replace(hour=0)
Out[3]: Timestamp('2014-11-12 00:35:00')
In [4]: ts
Out[4]: Timestamp('2014-11-12 13:35:00')
```

Note: ts is not modified in the code above.

```
In [5]: ts = ts.replace(hour=0)
In [6]: ts
Out[6]: Timestamp('2014-11-12 00:35:00')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `datetime.datetime`, use `datetime.date` and it will automatically truncate the hour/minute/second for you.

See https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#date-objects

Answer (score 1):

There is also [`Timestamp.floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html):

```py
>>> ts = pd.Timestamp('2014/11/12 13:35')
>>> ts.floor('D')
Timestamp('2014-11-12 00:00:00')
>>> ts.round('D')
Timestamp('2014-11-13 00:00:00')
```

But, on my machine, [`Timestamp.normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.normalize.html) is almost 30 times faster than `floor`, and [`Timestamp.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.replace.html) is even faster than `normalize`:

```
>>> %timeit ts.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
1.23 µs ± 17.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
>>> %timeit ts.normalize()
2.18 µs ± 137 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
>>> %timeit ts.floor('D')
62.7 µs ± 631 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.Timestamp('2014-11-12 13:35') - pd.offsets.Micro(0, normalize=True) == Timestamp('2014-11-12 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using:

```
pd.Timestamp('2014-11-12 13:35')-pd.Timedelta(f"{pd.Timestamp('2014-11-12 13:35').hour} hours")
```