# Round a Pandas Timestamp using an offset

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, resampling

I would like to round (floor) a Pandas `Timestamp` using a `pandas.tseries.offsets` (like when resampling time series but with just one row)

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset
freq = to_offset("H")
dt = pd.Timestamp('2017-01-03 05:02:00')
# what should I do
# to get pd.Timestamp('2017-01-03 05:00:00')
```

I wonder if `pandas.core.resample.TimeGrouper` can't help

```
grouper = pd.Grouper(freq="H")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamps may be rounded down using a time frequency string:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html

```
pd.Timestamp.now().floor('M')
pd.Timestamp.now().floor('H')
pd.Timestamp.now().floor('D')
```

Answer (score 2):

There may be a way to do it with offsets, but if you're just trying to "floor" timestamps to the format `'%H:00:00'`, you could also just use the `replace` method that `pd.Timestamps` inherit from `datetime.datetime` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26883852/6671176))

```
dt = pd.Timestamp('2017-01-03 05:02:00')

dt.replace(minute=0, second=0)

# Timestamp('2017-01-03 05:00:00')
```

If you wanted to do this on a whole column of datetimes, you could just apply it as a lambda:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2018-01-01 09:00:00','2018-01-01 10:00:00', freq='S'), columns = ['datetime'])

>>> df.head()
             datetime
0 2018-01-01 09:00:00
1 2018-01-01 09:00:01
2 2018-01-01 09:00:02
3 2018-01-01 09:00:03
4 2018-01-01 09:00:04

df['datetime'] = df.datetime.apply(lambda x: x.replace(minute=0, second=0))

>>> df.head()
0   2018-01-01 09:00:00
1   2018-01-01 09:00:00
2   2018-01-01 09:00:00
3   2018-01-01 09:00:00
4   2018-01-01 09:00:00
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm looking for a solution with an offset, and want to simply be able to change "H" to "4H", "1D" ...