# Error in replacing 'hour' and 'minute' of pandas TimeStamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm creating a datetime variable with pandas using `pd.to_datetime()`
The referenced dataframe only has the date (e.g. 31/12/2023) so the function returns it with time 00:00:00 (e.g. 31/12/2023 00:00:00) and now I want to set the time value individually with the `replace()` function following the examples shown in these two SO posts ([ex1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468823/python-datetime-setting-fixed-hour-and-minute-after-using-strptime-to-get-day), [ex2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882499/reset-time-part-of-a-pandas-timestamp)), but that leads to an error: *TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hour'*

Here is the code:

```
end = pd.to_datetime(df_end_date, dayfirst=True).replace(hour=23, minute=59)
```

The expression *df_end_date* has a single value, see screenshot (1) below or [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBghn.png).

The complete error message is shown in screenshot (2) below or [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h11sa.png).

Screenshot (1):

[image]

[image]

Screenshot (2):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `df_end_date` is scalar, solution working:

```
df_end_date = '31/12/2023'

end = pd.to_datetime(df_end_date, dayfirst=True).replace(hour=23, minute=59)
print (end)
2023-12-31 23:59:00
```

If `Series`, here one element `Series` need:

```
df_end_date = pd.Series(['31/12/2023'])
print (df_end_date)
0    31/12/2023
dtype: object

end = pd.to_datetime(df_end_date, dayfirst=True) + pd.offsets.DateOffset(hour=23, minute=59)
print (end)
0   2023-12-31 23:59:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or:

```
end = pd.to_datetime(df_end_date, dayfirst=True).map(lambda x: x.replace(hour=23,minute=59))
print (end)
0   2023-12-31 23:59:00
dtype: datetime64[ns
```