# Column with string date value to only date type in python not datetime. Or how to remove timestamp after converting

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

[`Datatype of two objects`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyyJq.png)

```
df_patients['date_of_diagnosis_new'] = pd.to_datetime(df_patients['date_of_diagnosis'])
```

Tried following code but got an error this error "AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'"

```
df_patients['date'] = df_patients['date_of_diagnosis'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d'))
```

Imported libraries:
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

```
Original Format  Desired Format
3/27/2010        2010-03-27
3/2/2011         2011-03-02
7/20/2009        2009-07-20
```

Comment: use `df_patients['date_of_diagnosis_new'] = pd.to_datetime(df_patients['date_of_diagnosis']).dt.date`

Comment: Now the output is in 'datetime.date(2012, 1, 1)' format. I want it in '2010-03-27' so that I can find out the difference between two dates in terms of days. There are two date columns and I need to find the difference between them. I'm able to calculate the difference with the timestamp '196 days 00:00:00' I just need to remove the timestamp now

Comment: then use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41718815/2901002)

Comment: Still not able to get the difference 'df_patients['date_of_diagnosis_new'] = pd.to_datetime(df_patients['date_of_diagnosis']).dt.date
df_patients['date_of_final_obs_new'] = pd.to_datetime(df_patients['date_of_final_obs']).dt.date
df_time['time_to_death'] = (df_time['date_of_final_obs_new'] -  df_time['date_of_diagnosis_new'])'

Comment: what is your code which does not work?

Comment: `df_time = df_patients.copy()
df_time['date_of_diagnosis'] = pd.to_datetime(df_patients['date_of_diagnosis'])
df_time['date_of_final_obs'] = pd.to_datetime(df_patients['date_of_final_obs'])
df_time['time_to_death'] = (df_time['date_of_final_obs'] -  df_time['date_of_diagnosis'])
print("Median time of death:",df_time['time_to_death'].median())`

Comment: The output is **Median time of death: 196 days 00:00:00** I want it to be just **196** days in integer

Comment: Use `print("Median time of death:",df_time['time_to_death'].median().days) `

Comment: Thanks! that worked. And what if I want to get the number of days before calculating the median. That is the difference between two dates in term of days in an integer type?