# xarray/datetime64[ns]: remove or normalise time from datetime

Tags: python-xarray

I have a data array `arr` with coordinate 'time'.
`arr`:

```
    <xarray.DataArray 'T' (time: 731)>
array([244.40161, 244.39998, ..., 244.40936, 244.40549], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * time         (time) datetime64[ns] 1979-01-01T09:00:00 ... 1980-12-31T09:00:00
```

Extracting the first 5 time coordinates,  `arr.time.values[:5]`:

```
array(['1979-01-01T09:00:00.000000000', '1979-01-02T09:00:00.000000000',
       '1979-01-03T09:00:00.000000000', '1979-01-04T09:00:00.000000000',
       '1979-01-05T09:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

I want the format of my date-time to just be `'1979-01-01'`, `'1979-01-02'` etc. without the time, or normalise the time at 00:00:00.

There are some solutions for pandas data frame but I'm not quite sure how to apply them here since the functions aren't applicable ([Converting between datetime, Timestamp and datetime64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64), [Keep only date part when using pandas.to_datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176996/keep-only-date-part-when-using-pandas-to-datetime))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this. The quick and dirty way I often use is uses resample:

```
da.resample(time='1D').first()
```

Something that is a bit more robust would be modify the time index directly:

```
da['time'] = da.indexes['time'].normalize()
```

Finally, this can be done generally by creating a new datetime index:

```
da['time'] = pd.date_range(da['time'][0], periods=len(da['time']), freq='1D')
```

Note that the second and third examples are going to be computationally cheaper than the first but does require working directly with the underling Pandas index.

Comment: Many thanks - this is a neat direct way as it doesn't require converting into a dataframe first etc., `arr['time'] = arr.indexes['time'].normalize()` worked perfectly where `arr` is an xarray data array. What is the difference between the second and third example you gave?

Comment: In this case, my 2nd and 3rd examples are basically the same operation. The third is a bit more extensible as you could use it to replace any existing time index.