# ValueError while plotting in xarray : view limit minimum -0.001 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

passing non-datetime values to matplotlib using xarrays.
How to convert them in proper format.

I tried solving the issue with this answer [xarray/datetime64[ns]: remove or normalise time from datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653536/xarray-datetime64ns-remove-or-normalise-time-from-datetime) but still the error continues.

The current format looks something like this:

```py
ds.time.values[:5]
```

Output:

```py
array(['1901-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '1901-01-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1901-01-03T00:00:00.000000000', '1901-01-04T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1901-01-05T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try date2num function from datetime library of python