# Python: How to Drop Hours from a Datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, hour

I have an issue that is plaguing me. Importing some data from .csv into Python gives a vector of dates in the format:

EDIT: Actually, it's not a vector of dates. Data is imported into a dataframe, so what I have to work on is a `DatetimeIndex` object.

```
1961-01-01 09:00:00
```

I want to drop the hours part and keep only the YYYY-MM-DD part, but I can not find a way to do it. Pandas `to_datetime` does not do what I need:

```
pd.to_datetime("1961-01-01 09:00:00", format=('%Y-%m-%d'))

Timestamp('1961-01-01 09:00:00')
```

While datetime.strptime would not just drop the hour:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
dt.strptime("1961-01-01 09:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d")

ValueError: unconverted data remains:  09:00:00
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT 2: Thanks to @WeizhongTu, I found a solution. Operating on the dataframe with `DatetimeIndex` index we can use:

```
mydf.index = mydf.index.values.astype('M8[D]')
```

That gives:

```
mydf.index[0:10]
DatetimeIndex(['1961-01-01', '1961-01-02', '1961-01-03', '1961-01-04',
               '1961-01-05', '1961-01-06', '1961-01-07', '1961-01-08',
               '1961-01-09', '1961-01-10'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: you can use `pd.to_datetime("1961-01-01 09:00:00", format=('%Y-%m-%d')).dt.date` to drop the hours directly while converting it

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176996/keep-only-date-part-when-using-pandas-to-datetime