# subtracting part of a column in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a date column in a `dataframe` but its type is string :

```
palma.Created_at[1:5]
```

```
- 1    2019-10-20 12:08:40 +0200
- 2    2019-10-20 12:08:40 +0200
- 3    2019-10-20 12:08:40 +0200
- 4    2019-10-20 12:08:40 +0200
- 5    2019-10-20 12:08:40 +0200
- Name: Created_at, dtype: object
```

and I want to be just like : `2019-10-20`. So how to  convert it like this and should I convert it to date type or no?

Comment: can you post the raw output of `palma.Created_at[1:5]` without bullet points?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep only date part when using pandas.to\_datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176996/keep-only-date-part-when-using-pandas-to-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
import pandas as pd

palma.Created_at = pd.to_datetime(palma.Created_at).dt.date
```

Comment: dt is the column name that i want to change right ?

Comment: and hwo do i subtract only the year-month-day from it ?

Comment: @MohyMohamed sorry, I missed the column name - have edited my answer. You still need `dt` to access the datetime part

Comment: "hwo do i subtract only the year-month-day from it " I don't understand, can you give an example?

Comment: i want the column become instead of `2019-10-20 12:08:40 +0200` to be `2019-10-20`

Comment: OK, I think what I've written should do that, can you try?