# Python: Increasing day on a Date string

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, hour

I've been trying to add one day to the following string: '01/05/2020'
The code below works, but it outputs with the hour information as well, which is not what I'm looking for.
I'm looking for a simple dd/mm/yyyy output. 
Do you know what I need to change to get to that?

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

day = '01/05/2020'
date = pd.to_datetime(day, format='%d/%m/%Y')
print((date + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
```

Output:

```
02/05/2020  00:00:00
```

Desired Output:

```
02/05/2020
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: print((date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176996/keep-only-date-part-when-using-pandas-to-datetime
maybe this will help you !

Comment: if you just want to print the date, `print((date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).date())` - if you want to work with date and time, have a look at the difference between strings and datetime objects ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the the below code. `date()` function will give you the desired result.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

day = '01/05/2020'
date = pd.to_datetime(day, format='%d/%m/%Y')
print((date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).date())
```

Comment: @MTavares I am glad it worked, could you please mark it as answered and upvote the answer if possible, so that community members know that this has been answered, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In pd.to_datetime() method format='%d/%m/%Y' specifies the input format. The output format will always be a Timestamp if a scalar is passed.

You can then convert the output to string using strftime() method as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

day = '01/05/2020'
date = pd.to_datetime(day)
print((date + timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%d/%m/%y"))
```

Or you can use .date() method to output date only.

Comment: Thank you! .date() format worked perfectly, and I found it simpler than using .strftime