# how to format date format in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, format

I use python and pandas to get yahoo stock market date and save to a local csv file.

```
DailyPrice = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=0)
print(DailyPrice.tail())

Date
2020-05-27           86.480003  84.370003  86.300003  86.180000  1917600.0 
2020-05-28           87.849998  86.059998  86.870003  86.690002  1908700.0
```

then I update the date.

```
History = pdr.DataReader(ticker, start=Before_yesterday, end=Today, data_source='yahoo')
print(History.tail())

Date
2020-06-29  87.360001  86.110001  86.559998  87.290001  1302500.0  87.290001
2020-06-30  88.379997  87.235001  87.330002  88.269997   236377.0  88.269997
```

then I append date

```
DailyPrice = DailyPrice.append(History)
print(DailyPrice.tail())

Date
2020-05-27           86.480003  84.370003  86.300003  86.180000  1917600.0 
2020-05-28           87.849998  86.059998  86.870003  86.690002  1908700.0
2020-06-29 00:00:00  87.360001  86.110001  86.559998  87.290001  1302500.0
2020-06-30 00:00:00  88.379997  87.235001  87.330002  88.269997   236377.0
```

so, my question is :
how coul I format the column Date just like %Y-%m-%d, without time hh:mm:ss?

Comment: from the example data you posted, it looks like you have mixed data types or only string data type in `df['Date']` - you might want to convert to datetime first; `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')`. After that you should be able to format via `df['Date'].dt.date`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep only date part when using pandas.to\_datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176996/keep-only-date-part-when-using-pandas-to-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is the same question as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176996/keep-only-date-part-when-using-pandas-to-datetime)

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.date
```

It should work

Comment: I have searched and tried, this does not work for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a [DatetimeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html), you could try to use [strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html)

```
DailyPrice.index = DailyPrice.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I find the problem.

Date is not a name of column.

```
DailyPrice.columns.values.tolist()
['High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close']
```

so, the first column, Date, what's it?

Date is the index.

at last, issue is resolved.

```
DailyPrice.index = pd.to_datetime(DailyPrice.index, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
```