# Rread excel without formatting date

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

Pandas 1.1.0
Python 3.8

When i tried to read a excel file with [read_excel method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

the file is loaded fine, but the excel has date formatting in some columns and pandas change the format automatically

I want to avoid this behavior

Comment: Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176996/keep-only-date-part-when-using-pandas-to-datetime)

Comment: can you `print(df.dtypes)` under the hood, the format is immaterial, a datetime is just a number - or the number of ticks since epoch. you can change the format back to default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the dtypes parameter in read_excel function like

```
df=pd.read_excel('excel.xlsx', dtypes={'datecolumnname1':str, 'datecolumnnam2':str,...})
```