# How do I convert numpy.datetime64('2022-04-20T00:00:00.000000000') to datetime.date(2022, 4, 04)

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, datetime-format

I have a column `df['Date]` which is a datetime64[ns] type and after doing the

```py
sheets= sorted(df['Date'].unique(), reverse =True)
```

I get a `numpy.datetime64('2022-04-20T00:00:00.000000000')` format, but I want it to be of this format `datetime.date(2022, 2, 16)`.

Comment: May be try the most upvoted answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176996/keep-only-date-part-when-using-pandas-to-datetime?

Comment: maybe you should use `df.sort_values()` instead of `sorted()` and then you would still have `DataFrame` so you could use `.apply()`. OR you should use `.apply` before `.unique`

Answer (score 0):

try to use something like this :

```
test = datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-04-20T00:00:00.000Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
new_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
test.strftime(new_format)
```