# Why isn't datetime.time not working on a column, but dt.time does?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a df with a column 'start date'. It has date values. They are of string type. The column also has blank values.

```
--> df.loc[0,'start date']
output : '2022-10-04'
--> type(df.loc[0,'start date'])
output : str
```

I have imported datetime

```
import datetime
```

And I try to convert this entire column to pandas datetime type.

```
df['start date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start date'], errors='coerce')
```

Because this will give time stamp as well, I want to keep only the date, I did this:

```
df['start date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start date'], errors='coerce').datetime.date
```

But this gives an Attribute error :AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'datetime'
Whereas if I tweak the code to :

```
df['start date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start date'], errors='coerce').dt.date
```

It works!

What's happening?! Any help in understanding the concept behind this would be appreciated :)

Comment: because the accessor is named `dt` and not `datetime`… this is a design choice of pandas developers, nothing more

Comment: @mozway when I write import datetime, I am importing a module which has functions, classes, and variables. Right?

Comment: @SoumyaPandey you don't need to import datetime yourself, the pandas dt attribute works on its own through the pandas package

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68672660/1328439 related question on how to keep only the date part of a pandas Series.

Comment: `import datetime` imports the Python standard library module 'datetime' - `pandas` doesn't use that to represent date/time, see [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html). However, you can use it *in combination* with pandas datetime.