# Capturing Date/Month/year from Datetime object

Tags: pandas

In Pandas how do I capture only the date/month/year  excluding the time from a datetime object?
The code is returning 23/04/2021  00:00:00 as datetime64 object but I would like to capture only 23/04/2021 from that object .
Regards
Syed

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following will work, using "[dt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#dt-accessor)"

```
df['just_date'] = df['dates'].dt.date
```

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176996/keep-only-date-part-when-using-pandas-to-datetime)